# OCR Preprocessing: Remove lines crossing characters

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision

I'm currently trying to improve the recognition rate of [GoogleCloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/), so I am building a preprocessing pipeline.

I currently can create a mask which overlays the characters in the image, but as you can see in the examples below, it also shows the lines. Now since those lines can cross through characters, I'd like to remove them from the mask without destroying the characters, if possible.

Current steps:

Line detection:
InputImage -> Grayscale -> Blackhat -> GaussianBlur -> Threshhold(OTSU) -> HoughLinesP

Mask generation: InputImage -> Grayscale -> Blackhat -> GaussianBlur -> Threshhold(OTSU)-> ConnectedComponents

ImageExamples:(Due to privacy protection, sharing a full Image is not possible)

[image: Region in original image]
[image: Current Mask]
[image: Recognized lines]

The images show the original image, the mask and the lines recognized.
The following code is used to generate the mask and find the lines

```
Mat picture = Imgcodecs.imread(path);
Imgproc.cvtColor(picture, picture, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("/home/meik/Pictures/asdfGray.png", picture);
Mat blackhatElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.CV_SHAPE_RECT, new Size(7, 7));

Imgproc.morphologyEx(picture, picture, Imgproc.MORPH_BLACKHAT, blackhatElement);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(picture, picture, new Size(5, 3), 0);
Imgproc.threshold(picture, picture, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY | Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

/**
 * Line Detection with Canny and HoughLines(P)
 */
Mat lines = new Mat();
Mat linesResult = Mat.zeros(picture.rows(),picture.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.HoughLinesP(picture, lines,1, Math.PI/180,100, 20, 0);
System.out.println("lines rows:" + lines.rows());
for (int x = 0; x < lines.rows(); x++) {
    double[] l = lines.get(x, 0);
    Imgproc.line(linesResult, new Point(l[0], l[1]), new Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, Imgproc.LINE_8, 0);
}
/**End of line detection*/
Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.CV_SHAPE_CROSS, new Size(3,3));
Imgproc.dilate(linesResult,linesResult,kernel);
Core.bitwise_not(linesResult,linesResult);
```

I've found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320066537_An_Efficient_Technique_for_Detection_and_Removal_of_Lines_with_Text_Stroke_Crossings_in_Document_Images) talking about the problem, but am struggling to understand their methodology.

How do I proceed from here on to remove lines without destroying the characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really think you need to refer paper to do this.

Just use color info or  hough line to find out a straightline which is really long

use that info to create a mask image.

Then use the opencv inpaint to remove it.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html

e.g. what you want is similar to the bottom image. It ask to remove the traffic light poles.  and you want the writing guideline to be removed. essentially, its the same thing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about some simple image preprocessing?
For example using a threshold to only maintain a certain color range (instead of directly converting the image to grayscale).

Something like this is integrated in GIMP, see
https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-threshold.html

You probably want to experiment with various thresholds.